# add edges only on the z-axis (with geometry nodes if possible)

Tags: geometry-nodes, wireframe

I have a model (picture 1) that has some modifiers added to make it look like an abstract wireframe thing (picture 2). The Modifiers are: subdivision surface --> decimate --> displace --> subdivision surface --> wireframe (maybe will be exchanged with skin to show internal wireframe) --> subdivision surface. I weightpainted it to make it look more organic. The plan is to 3d print it and make light shine through from the backside so it casts shadows (for a kinetic sculpture). My problem is that i like the big holes because it will let a lot of light shine through it but the 3d printer will have problems to print such long overhangs. My plan was to add more support edges but only in the z-axis so that when viewed from top the added edges are hidden es much es possible. Preferably i want to add them non-destructive/procedurally AND not only on the outside mesh but also on the internal to fill the volume with support. Is that possible with geometry nodes? Thank you very much in advance - this community already helped me a lot.
[image: basic mesh]

[image: mesh with added modifiers]

[image: visual description]